# How do edit controls work internally? class windowProcedure and allocated buffers

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, edit, msdn

`CreateWindowEx` creates a window, and if you set the `lpClassName` parameter as `"Edit"` it creates an edit box.

I know that `lpClassName` has his own `WindowProcedure` registered to its structure. That procedure handles all messages that interact with the edit box.

Suppose we have a few edit boxes, and that each edit box has its own buffer. What I don't understand is, how does that `WindowProcedure` know which buffer to handle? For example, on a key pressed, or when you use `SendMessage()`/`GetMessage()` and you pass only the window handle. Because, you don't specify which buffer to use, how is that buffer determined by the shared (between edit controls) `WindowsProcedure`?

I suppose that is somehow internal. But how? Does it have an internal list of edit box structures in which it associates the window handle with the allocated buffer for each edit box, and loops through them to find the buffer determined by the handle?

Comment: I imagine the window structure itself stores a pointer to the buffer. The window procedure is passed the windows handle. See the function GetWindowLongPtr.

Comment: See [`RegisterClassEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw), [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) (particularly the `cbWndExtra` field), and [`GetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw). That's how you can store arbitrary per-window data and only need the window handle to retrieve it (which the window procedure is passed).

Comment: Maybe I understood it wrong but I thought that the WNDCLASSEXW structure is the same for all Edit Controls because you Register it once in the system. But I didnt't knew that each EditControl gets an object( instance ) of this structure allocated to it. I will test if this is true with my WNDCLASSEXW structure and i will try to create with CreateWindowEx multiple Windows of my class and test if it is so.

Comment: I asked the above question because I have my own structures/instances and don't know how to implement them right in a win32 c++ application. How do you usually do? How do you structure your application when you want to build desktop forms applications with win32 api?

Comment: WNDCLASSEX is used once to register a class, and as part of that you tell the system how many extra bytes of data **every** window of that class gets allocated. The extra window data is accessed via GetWindowLongPtr/SetWindowLongPtr.

Answer (score 0):

When the Edit box is created, it likely creates an object in memory to save information about the Edit's data, state, etc, and then saves that object in the `HWND` itself (HOW it is saved is an implementation detail - for example, `WNDCLASS::cbWndExtra` could be used to set aside extra bytes inside the `HWND` to hold a pointer to the object).  The buffer would be a member of that object.  The `HWND` simply refers to the window that owns the object, and the Edit's `WindowProc` knows how the object is stored and thus how to access it (ie, by using `GetWindowLongPtr()`, etc) from whichever `HWND` is given to it.  There is no list to look through.

If you want *definitive implementation details*, you will have to ask Microsoft for that (or otherwise reverse-engineer the `user32` and `comctl32` libraries, or find leaked source code online).

Comment: For reference, I used Spy++ on Notepad's edit control, and it shows *Window Bytes* (on the "Class" tab) as 8, i.e. the size of a pointer on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: ... or get the leaked source code and look for yourself ;)